# variable keeps printing properties if the swing content then the value itself

Tags: java, swing, variables

Following is the basic content of the code where inside the constructor class i have a java swing text field and all im trying to do is get the text from it and save it in a variable as a integer but it keeps printing the styling of the textfield I set then the value. If i say to print agestr in the method, it prints correct bit its a string. I used the string to int translator then it freaks out and prints all these other stuff.

```
Constructor(){
   private JTextField age = new JTextField("12");
   String agestr=age.getText().toString();
   aMethod(agestr);
}
Public void aMethod(String agestr){
   try{
      int age=Integer.parInt(agestr);
   }catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
   System.out.println(age);
}
```

while running, i get:

> javax.swing.JTextField[,268,86,214x20,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@695bc558,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]

its basically the swing code for a component somewhere.

Comment: I cant compile your code. The method `aMethod` is declared as taking a String as parameter, but in the constructor you call it with `aMethod(age);` where `age` is declared as a `JTextField`?! And in `aMethod` you call `System.out.println(age);` - again with `age` being the `JTextField`.

Comment: Sounds about right. i made few changes and renamed the age to age1 inside the method and it worked. Thank you alot. I thought it would override the textfield value but didnt realize its different object.

Comment: no random code snippets please (yours wouldn't even compile) - instead provide a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected (if an error is thrown, also post the complete stacktrace formatted as code)